# How to install webpy framework on Windows

Tags: python, web.py

I have python 3.3.2 installed on windows 8 x64.

I am trying to install webpy framework. What I tried:

Downloaded latest webpy.
Extracted to python directroy.
in command promp I cd {python_dir/webpy_sub_dir}, then
python setup.py install

I get this error:

```
Traceback ....
  File "setup.py", line 6 ....
  from web import __version__
  File ........ /web/__init__.py, line 14 in <module>
  import utils,db,net,wcgi,http,webapi, .........
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

What could be the problem? I could not find any tutorials relating to windows installs.

P.S. I realise this is borderline "not a programming question" but looking at other stack forums there isn't a better place for this(IMO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was that webpy is not compatible with python 3.x. I went with a similar alternative - bottle py.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to download the utils package from pypi

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-utils/

Comment: How do I install it? I tried the same method as in the original question but now get an error "No module named setuptools".

Comment: Did you try installing setuptools?

Comment: I did not and it installed successfully, so did the utils but webpy still fails with same error - "No module named utils".

Answer (score 1):

Web.py is been ported to python 3.
You can join mail list and help